Unable to find a valid endpoint for function `ext-firestore-bundle-builder-serve`
When trying to deploy my firebase project with the bundler extension, I get the following warning:

⚠  hosting[project]: Unable to find a valid endpoint for function ext-firestore-bundle-builder-serve, but still including it in the config

This is what my firebase.json looks like:
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "europe-west1"
    },
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/bundles/*",
        "function": "ext-firestore-bundle-builder-serve"
      }
    ]
  }
}

What am I missing here?

I managed to get rid of the warning by enabling the extension "Firestore Bundle Builder" in the Firebase Console.
